# SELECT * FROM table in addition of aggregation function

Tags: sql, join, aggregation

Short context:
I would like to show a list of all companies except if they are in the sector 'defense' or 'government' and their individual total spent on training classes. Only the companies that have this total amount above 1000 must be shown.

So I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE, CITY, SUM(FEE-PROMOTION) AS "Total spent on training at REX"
FROM COMPANY INNER JOIN PERSON ON (COMPANY_NUMBER = EMPLOYER) INNER JOIN ENROLLMENT ON (PERSON_ID = STUDENT)
WHERE SECTOR_CODE NOT IN (SELECT CODE 
              FROM SECTOR 
              WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'Government' OR DESCRIPTION = 'Defense')
GROUP BY NAME, ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE, CITY
HAVING SUM(FEE-PROMOTION) > 1000
ORDER BY SUM(FEE-PROMOTION) DESC
```

Now what I actually need is, instead of defining every single column in the COMPANY table, I would like to show ALL columns of the COMPANY table using *.

```
SELECT * (all tables from COMPANY here), SUM(FEE-PROMOTION) AS "Total spent on training at REX"
FROM COMPANY INNER JOIN PERSON ON (COMPANY_NUMBER = EMPLOYER) INNER JOIN ENROLLMENT ON (PERSON_ID = STUDENT)
WHERE SECTOR_CODE NOT IN (SELECT CODE 
              FROM SECTOR 
              WHERE DESCRIPTION = 'Government' OR DESCRIPTION = 'Defense')
GROUP BY * (How to fix it here?)
HAVING SUM(FEE-PROMOTION) > 1000
ORDER BY SUM(FEE-PROMOTION) DESC
```

I could define every single column from COMPANY in the SELECT and that solution will do the job (as in the first example), but how can I make the query shorter using "SELECT * from the table COMPANY"?

Comment: With this: `SELECT COMPANY.*`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is to summarize in the subquery to get the total spend for the company.  This allows you to remove the aggregation from the outer query:

```
select c.*, pe.total_spend
from company c join
     sector s
     on c.sector_code = s.code left join
     (select p.employer, sum(e.fee - e.promotion) as training_spend
      from person p join
           enrollment e
           on p.person_id = e.student
      group by p.employer
     ) pe
     on pe.employer = c.company_number
where s.sector not in ('Government', 'Defense') and
      pe.total_spend > 1000
```